# How to create Getter and Setter for TableView

Tags: java, dynamic, tableview, setter, getter

```
public class CatTable {


private SimpleStringProperty nameCat1;
private SimpleStringProperty nameCat2;
    private SimpleStringProperty nameCat3;
    private SimpleStringProperty nameCat4;
    private SimpleStringProperty nameCat5;
    private SimpleStringProperty nameCat6;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    private SimpleStringProperty nameCat100;

    public CatTable(){
    this.nameCat1 = new SimpleStringProperty();     
    this.nameCat2 = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.nameCat3 = new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.nameCat4 = new SimpleStringProperty();
            .
            .
            .
    this.nameCat100 = new SimpleStringProperty();
}

    public CatTable(String nameCat1, String nameCat2, ... , nameCat100){
    this.nameCat1 = new SimpleStringProperty(numCat1);
    this.nameCat2= new SimpleStringProperty(nameCat2);
             .
             .
             .
    this.nameCat100= new SimpleStringProperty(nameCat100);
}

public String getNameCat1(){
    return nameCat1.get();
}

public void setNameCat1(String numCat1){
    this.nameCat1.set(nameCat1);
}

public String getNameCat2(){
    return nameCat2.get();
}
public void setNameCat2(String nameCat2){
    this.nameCat2.set(nameCat2);
}

    .
    .
    .
     public String getNameCat100(){
    return nameCat100.get();
    }
    public void setNameCat100(String nameCat100){
    this.nameCat100.set(nameCat100);
```

I try to make tableview with getter and setter.
and if there are 100 tableColumns. i make each getters and setters for columns

Does anyone know how to make it simple?
I have no idea at all.

Comment: Have you heard of lists or arrays?

Comment: i tried but does not work perfectly...

Comment: If you don't want to use collection to store columns, you can use reflection API to generate each getter and setter in runtime :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a data structure to help you out. Consider using a list.

```
public class CatTable {
    List<SimpleStringProperty> properties = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addProperty(SimpleStringProperty property) {
        properties.add(property);
    }
    public SimpleStringProperty getProperty(int index) {
        return properties.get(index);
    }
    public String getPropertyValue(int index) {
        return getProperty(index).get();
    }
    // other stuff...
}
```

This way you have a single point of storage and only one method to get any properties you need. Keep in mind Java's lists are 0 based so when you add property 1 it will be stored at index 0.